# Trying to adapt code form one of my views to be rendered in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a partial that takes a column from a database a iterates over it and displays all the urls on the web page. I want to add the lines that I have written in my `app/views/topics/show.html.erb` page that allow the user to edit, delete, or like the link.

These are the three lines I want to adapt to be added to the partial, the first two are buttons to carry out the edit and delete function and the third is a link to a partial with the like code.

```
<%= link_to "Edit bookmark", edit_topic_bookmark_path(bookmark.topic, bookmark), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'%><br>
<%= link_to "Delete bookmark", [bookmark.topic, bookmark], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this bookmark?' } %>
<%= render partial: 'likes/likes', locals: { bookmark: bookmark } %>
```

this is the partial I would like to adapt it to located in `app/views/bookmarks/_bookmarksandlikes.html.erb`

```
<div>
    <h3>
        <%y=1%>
        <% mark.each do |x| %>
            <%=y%>)<%= link_to x.url, x.url%>
            <%y=y+1%>

        <% end %>
    </h3>
</div>
```

and it is being called from `app/views/users/show.html.erb` with these two lines.

```
 <%= render partial: 'bookmarks/bookmarksandlikes', locals: { mark: @bookmarks} %>
 <%= render partial: 'bookmarks/bookmarksandlikes', locals: { mark: @liked_bookmarks} %>
```

here is how I have tried to insert the code into the partial

```
<div>
  <h3>
    <%y=1%>
    <% mark.each do |x| %>
      <%=y%>)<%= link_to x.url, x.url%>
      <%y=y+1%>
      <%= link_to "Edit bookmark", edit_topic_bookmark_path(x.topic, x), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'%><br>
      <%= link_to "Delete bookmark", [x.topic, x], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this bookmark?' } %>
      <%= render partial: 'likes/likes', locals: { x: x } %>
   <%end%>
 </h3>
```

when I run the code as is I get an error page that says "`undefined local variable or method 'bookmark' for #<#<Class:0x007fdfb1b39c80>:0x007fdfb1988d50> Did you mean?  bookmark_url or @bookmarks`

and says there is a problem on line 3 of the partial with the code for liking a page in `app/views/likes/_likes.html.erb`

```
<% if policy(Like.new).create? %>
  <div>
    <% if like = current_user.liked(bookmark) %>
    <%= link_to [bookmark, like], class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>&nbsp; Unlike
    <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to [bookmark, Like.new], class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>&nbsp; Like
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

side note at this point in working through this problem, it appears that only the third line for the partial I am trying to insert is giving me problems, the edit and delete buttons are rendering nicely.

Even if you don't know the answer I am quite keen to hear any thoughts on what I am not considering in this question or just your thoughts, also if you need more information please just let me know and I will post more.

Thanks for looking at my question.

Comment: So what is the problem you are running into?

Comment: I was getting a error message that said "`undefined local variable or method bookmark for #<#<Class:0x007fdfb1b39c80>:0x007fdfb1c67ee0>Did you mean?  bookmark_url or @bookmarks`

also thank you for asking that, it made me go back and examine a few things.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, I could not use the partial because the partial `app/views/likes/_likes.html.erb` was taking in a different variable than was being passed by `app/views/bookmarks/_bookmarksandlikes.html.erb` so I just put the needed code into `app/views/bookmarks/_bookmarksandlikes.html.erb` and adapted it like so.

```
<div class=row>
    <h3>
        <%y=1%>
        <% mark.each do |x| %>
        <%=y%>)<%= link_to x.url, x.url%><br>
        <%y=y+1%>
        <%= link_to "Edit bookmark", edit_topic_bookmark_path(x.topic, x), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs'%><br>
        <%= link_to "Delete bookmark", [x.topic, x], method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this bookmark?' } %><br>
        <% if like = current_user.liked(x) %>
        <%= link_to [x, like], class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :delete do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></i>&nbsp; Unlike
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to [x, Like.new], class: 'btn btn-primary', method: :post do %>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>&nbsp; Like
        <% end %>
        <br>
        <% end %>
        <%end%>

    </h3>
  </div>
```